# Gvim-How to remove the bottom big white bar of gvim?

Tags: vim

I have a big white bar in the bottom of gvim which is very irritating. can anyone please explain how to remove the white bar at the bottom.
[image: If you observe the white bar at bottom]

suggest any solution. thanks in advance.
this also occurs in terminal.

Comment: Please help us help you. Operating system (and used desktop environment / window manager / whatever is relevant), Vim version?

Comment: I am using gvim in xubuntu utopic unicorn, vim 7.4.52, in xfce environment.

Comment: If in full screen only, then it is simply the remainder that is too small to fit another line. Try increasing font sizes and see if there are sizes where the line goes away (or gets bigger). If so, that is the reason.

Comment: @Jens I tried changing the font sizes but it is of no use.

Comment: @Jens yep..true decresed the font further and all good now..thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in full screen only, then it is simply the remainder that is too small to fit another line. Try increasing or decreasing the font size and see if there are sizes where the line goes away (or gets bigger). If so, that is the reason.

Answer (score 0):

I found this trouble when using

```
:tabnew
```

I read from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim, it caused by window Manager that ignore window size hints. Set this in ~/.vimrc

```
:set guiheadroom=0
```

But sometimes cause the last line missing. So the best approach maybe set the right fontsize and don't use "e" in guioptions. In other word set in ~/.vimrc

```
:set guioptions-=e
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you think this should be set in `~/.vimrc` and not in `~/.gvimrc`?